# RecyclerView: How to add spacing, but keep initial view size

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, spacing, divider

The childviews of my recyclerView should fill the complete space, when they are centered, but between the views should be a spcing/gap.
All I found so far is this: [How to add dividers and spaces between items in RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618829/how-to-add-dividers-and-spaces-between-items-in-recyclerview) But in this case, the size of the views is reduced, so that I see the view and the spacing when the view is centered.

One approach could be to make the recyclerview display two types of views, the normal and the divider, but that seems overkill for such a simples task.

Fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/outerContainer">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/searchBarContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp">


    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/innerContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/searchBarContainer">

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Layout for RecyclerView item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.custom_view.news_feed.NewsFeedListItem
        android:id="@+id/newsFeedListItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Setting the adapter

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view, null);
innerContainer.addView(recyclerView);
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, true);
layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new VerticalSpaceItemDecoration(VERTICAL_ITEM_SPACE));
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

VerticalSpaceItemDecorationClass

```
public class VerticalSpaceItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private final int mVerticalSpaceHeight;

    public VerticalSpaceItemDecoration(int mVerticalSpaceHeight) {
        this.mVerticalSpaceHeight = mVerticalSpaceHeight;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent,
                               RecyclerView.State state) {
        outRect.bottom = mVerticalSpaceHeight;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618829/how-to-add-dividers-and-spaces-between-items-in-recyclerview

Comment: show your layout code