# For Android ListView, Is it possible to set a divider and create a padding for each listitem?

Tags: android, listview, styles

I want to create a Listview where each item has a divider and a padding or margin to other element, is that possible?

I only saw solutions where somebody used the divider as "padding or margin" because the color is the same as background. But i need both.

my style for the list:

```
<!-- res/values/styles.xml -->
<style name="ListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:background">@color/light_grey</item>
    <item name="android:cacheColorHint">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/list_item_selector</item>
</style>
```

Comment: you can do it with adding a `customAdapter` to your lisView and then you can create a complete customized layout for each of your listView items there you can add **margin** and **divider** for each of your items

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `layout.xml` add divider as color or `drawable`, and `dividerHeight` as shown below.

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:divider="#ff0000"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp">
```

to get the padding to each list item, Use a custom adapter,and put padding in `listitem.xml` layout file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp">

<!--your list item contents-->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a `customAdapter` like below :

```
public class customAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
...
}
```

and then implement the methods of `BaseAdapter` and in the `getView` method you can inflate your custom layout for each of the list view items like below :

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
// Get view for row item
View rowView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_recipe, parent, false);

return rowView;
}
```

visit this link has a very good example : http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67

Comment: I know you are helping, but try posting something more useful.. add a link to a guide, add an example of code, add some explaination.. this is kinda not an answer.. [please look here how to answer properly](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: srry I was trying to add more to my answer :)

Comment: seen, now it's waay better :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make an `ItemDecoration` and use it with a `RecyclerView` which is quite the same as a `ListView` but way more powerful.

See this question for more details: [How to add dividers and spaces between items in RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618829/how-to-add-dividers-and-spaces-between-items-in-recyclerview)