# DividerItemDecoration not showing up android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have this simple layout for recycler view items.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/details"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:paddingEnd="15dp"
android:paddingStart="15dp"
>

<org.tchouaffe.ftinfosystem.utils.CustomTextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
    android:textSize="15sp"/>


<org.tchouaffe.ftinfosystem.utils.CustomTextView
    android:id="@+id/level"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/name"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
    android:textSize="15sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the following code does sets up the recycler view:

```
 RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(activity, elementList);
    adapter.setHasStableIds(true);
    DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView
            .getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

For an unknown reason the divider is not showing up.
Any ideas?

I am using `android.support.v7.widget.DividerItemDecoration`.

Thanks

Comment: For Vertical check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27037230/2870088

Comment: what `Drawable` do you want to use?

Comment: Hi @pskink. What do you mean by Drawable?

Comment: Hi @AnuragSingh. There plenty of comments on that post. What should I look for?

Answer (score 6):

You also need to call [`setDrawable()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/DividerItemDecoration.html#setDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) on `DividerDecoration`.

Provide a drawable resource. An [XML shape drawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) can be a good start. The shape will be rendered as the divider between recycler item views.

Alternatively, when declaring the app theme, you can 
 set `android:listDivider` item to the desired drawable.

Comment: or setup `android:listDivider`, at least it seems to be working so, see [DividerItemDecoration.java#47](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/android-support-test/espresso/sample/src/main/java/android/support/test/testapp/DividerItemDecoration.java#47)

Comment: @pskink Indeed.

Comment: ooops posted wrong file, should be: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/recyclerview/src/android/support/v7/widget/DividerItemDecoration.java?autodive=0%2F#65, but still `android:listDivider` is used the same way

Comment: Hi @pskink. android:listDivider was missing. Big thanks

Comment: @S.D. it is not in layout file but in your current theme: `<item name="android:listDivider">@drawable/divider</item>`

Comment: @pskink Updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try using this vector as divider line

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="24dp"
android:height="2dp"
android:viewportWidth="24"
android:viewportHeight="2">
<path
    android:pathData="M0,0L100,0.5"
    android:strokeWidth="2"
    android:fillColor="#00000000"
    android:strokeColor="@color/lessons_divider_line_background"/>
```