# Android UI design

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I want give some style to each row of the following UI.
It shows simply a list of songs searched in my app but all the rows shown in a the same page without any kind of separation or a kind of line between each row.
My idea is to differentiate each song or each row. If there is a nice style or Theme that separate each row with different colors it would be awesome also.

This is my code;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:background="@drawable/white_selector"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:contentDescription="@string/audio_play"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/badges"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/play"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_play"
            android:contentDescription="@string/audio_play"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/duration"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            tools:text="3:05"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/logo"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/badges"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/badges"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        tools:text="Martin Garrix - Animals"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `View` to show a divider/line at the bottom of your row item view. Wrap your `RelativeLayout` with a new container `LinearLayout` and add a `View` inside `LinearLayout` to show line/divider. here I used `RED(#FF0000)` color for divider.

**Try this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:background="@drawable/white_selector"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:contentDescription="@string/audio_play"/>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/badges"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/play"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_play"
                android:contentDescription="@string/audio_play"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/duration"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                tools:text="3:05"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/logo"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/badges"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/badges"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            tools:text="Martin Garrix - Animals"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#FF0000">

    </View>
</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you tu use a [listvew](/questions/tagged/listvew) not only the design would be better but, as you said, you want to show a LIST of songs. You can still add images to the listview and add automatically a clicklistener to each of the items

Comment: Well, i am new to this and it took alot my time . İ want to work on this and make this a better one

Answer (score 0):

### Create List dynamically

You can use `RecyclerView` to achieve this (It's better than `ListView`, as it reuse the cells while scrolling and other improvements over `ListView`).

The easy way to use it, is using android studio to create a Fragment with dummy data and you need then to change the data to your model and do some changes.
Right click on your app module -> New -> Fragment -> Fragment (List)
[image: android]

Then in your activity you can show the fragment using `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(...)` or if you want to use it directly in your activity, then take look at the generated Fragment and adapt your activity to use the `RecyclerView`.

### Add divider between the items ([reference for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27037230/3469686))

```
DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(),
    layoutManager.getOrientation());
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
```