# how to add divider line/seperator to words store with sqlite in the recyclerview box

Tags: android, xml, offline, searchview

thankyou so much. Your solutions are helping me. i am doing a project called offline android dictionary. I av the search view and recycler view as my activity_main.xml. I stored and wrote my words using sqlite. And all my words are located in the recycler view box but my problem is that i don't know how to separate the words in the recycler view with divider line/seperator

Comment: Your question is too vague. You should add more details.

Comment: You can check this answer [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618829/how-to-add-dividers-and-spaces-between-items-in-recyclervie)

Answer (score 0):

To create a line **separator** for list items you could use this

```
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);

    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
```