# ImageView in CardView taking up whole screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-xml, android-cardview

Recently I've been trying to implement a `CardView` inside multiple horizontal `RecyclerView`. However, my CardView seems to be taking up the width of an entire screen when the image in the `ImageView` isn't exactly the size I have specified. I know this because it worked exactly the way I want to when I put in an image that matches the width dimensions. But I want the program to be able to crop images regardless of dimensions. 
[What I Want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtFCj.png)  And here is [what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7u4P.png) when the image used isn't the same width as the one specified in my xml file.

Here is my cardview that I use in my recyclerview.

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtRecipeSectionTitle"
            android:text="Recipe Section"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recipe_section_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="242dp"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the xml for my recyclerview. Though I don't think it's this thing's problem.

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="133dp"
    android:layout_height="242dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/recipeThumbnail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="195dp"
            android:contentDescription=""
            android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtRecipeName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/recipeThumbnail"
            android:text="Name of Recipe"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtCalorie"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtRecipeName"
            android:text="Calories: "
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtRecipeCalorie"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtRecipeName"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtCalorie"
            android:text="999"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtKcal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtRecipeName"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtRecipeCalorie"
            android:text="kcal"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

By the way, since we're all here, can someone tell me how to increase the spaces between each card? I'm currently using marginLeft inside the relative layout inside the `CardView` but that is definitely not the way to go.

Thanks in advance for you answer!

Comment: set same size of your `Imageview` as your `CardView` size. For set space between two item please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618829/how-to-add-dividers-and-spaces-between-items-in-recyclerview

Comment: Your `CardView` looks OK to me. How are you loading the images? When I past your XML in a sample project, photos are cropped and look like your desired image. btw, you have the two XML files switched in your question. Also, you should replace `fill_parent` (deprecated) with `match_parent`.

Answer (score 1):

Set a maximum width to your Imageview

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/recipeThumbnail"
            android:maxWidth="150dp"                 //Change to suit
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"           //Trims accordingly
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="195dp"
            android:contentDescription=""
            android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />
```

> By the way, since we're all here, can someone tell me how to increase
>   the spaces between each card? I'm currently using marginLeft inside
>   the relative layout inside the CardView but that is definitely not the
>   way to go.

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27037230/3505928) answer.