# Overlay of the elements in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have a following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#EEEEEE"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="4dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        />

    <TextView
        android:text="12345678911131517192123252729313335373941434547495153555759616365676971737577798183858789"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:text="  text text"
        android:id="@+id/prev"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="WHY WHY WHY"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/prev"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

We have a following result:
[image with this issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57s4r.png)

Besides, if we change the text of the first TextView to:  "1234567891113151719212325272931333537394143454749515355575961636567697173757779818385878991" (that is, add 2 more numbers), last TextView stops closing the previous one.

Also, if we change the layout_marginBottom attribute to 0dp in the last TextView  (and text is to leave as it was in the Example), problem also disappears. What is the reason of this problem? How to fix it?

**UPDATE:**

On the left side added a path which has a match_parent height. Because of this can not use paddingBottom in ConstraintLayout. The layout is used in RecyclerView, that is why the bottom element needs a layout_marginBottom.

Answer (score 1):

Either you remove the `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` from `textview3` or you change the height of the layout to `match_parent`.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I need exactly a wrap_content. If remove app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent", layout_marginBottom stops working.

Answer (score 0):

I think by removing `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` will solve your issue

This issue occurs because you have given parent ConstraintLayout `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` hence it automatically tries to arrange itself within specified boundaries

**EDIT:**

I have tried & tested below code which works in my `RecyclerView`, hope it works for you too.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#EEEEEE">

<!--Your Test ImageView-->
    <!--<ImageView
        android:layout_width="4dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />-->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="12345678911131517192123252729313335373941434547495153555759616365676971737577798183858789"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/prev"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="  text text"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="32dp"
        android:text="WHY WHY WHY"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/prev" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem completely, as the bottom margin disappears.

Comment: If it is the last widget that you need in your xml, then your `layout_marginBottom` will have no effect

Comment: No, it's just an example, in fact layout like this has background and is used in RecyclerView.

Comment: I suggest you remove it from `TextView` and put `layout_marginBottom` inside `ConstraintLayout`, that should fix your issue

Comment: If you are using `RecyclerView` then you can use `DividerItemDecoration` for spacing between items. View https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618829/how-to-add-dividers-and-spaces-between-items-in-recyclerview for more details

Comment: I know about an existance of DividerItemDecoration, but can not undertsand how it can help in this situation.
I don't need a space between the elements, margin from a bottom should be inside the element.

Answer (score 0):

the error happened because that line `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`
 in the last textview .. because ConstraintLayout like a RelativeLayout
jsut remove this line

Answer (score 0):

Remove `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` from textview3 like the others have suggested, and add `android:paddingBottom="8dp"` to the parent constraintLayout. You could also add a marginTop parameter to textview3 to space it from textview2.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue to this one [Problems with ConstraintLayout - vertical margin doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46584315/problems-with-constraintlayout-vertical-margin-doesnt-work) and the only solution is to use "packed" vertical chain. All those "...add/remove layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"..." are just tricks which solve problem for just particular cases.

Here's your layout with integrated "packed" vertical chain:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#EEEEEE" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="4dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="12345678911131517192123252729313335373941434547495153555759616365676971737577798183858789"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/prev"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <TextView
        android:text="  text text"
        android:id="@+id/prev"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:text="WHY WHY WHY"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/prev"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

It works properly for any text view length and ConstraintLayout wraps its content properly, look at this gif:

[image: Result view]

You can find more complex implementations of RecyclerView item layouts built with ConstraintLayout here https://github.com/eugenebrusov/cards.