# Problems with ConstraintLayout - ImageView 16:9 inappropriate top margin

Tags: android, android-imageview, margin, android-constraintlayout, constraint-layout-chains

I want to build the following layout using ConstraintLayout:

[image: Mockup]

I use this source for layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:srcCompat="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,16:9"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:text="Subtle"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView1"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

And unfortunately get this result:

[image: Result view]

As you can see there's an unnecessary margin on the top of ImageView, though layout indicates marginTop=0.

Comment: Your layout_gravity is center. Remove that and you should be good to go

Comment: @NSimon No, it doesn't help... See this screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/rftoxtk76jg3r6i/Screenshot_1507214820.png?dl=0

Comment: Remove this: app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView1"

Comment: @SuhaylSH If `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView1"` removed then somehow I get 40dp vertical distance between textView1 and imageView. See this screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/tjw1raf224aaq6l/device-2017-10-05-185647%20copy.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on answers and comments posted in reply to this question and considering the fact constraint-layout v1.1.0 is still in beta, the best solution at this moment would be to use `app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:srcCompat="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,16:9"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView1"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:text="Subtle"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView1"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need to get rid of this top margin

For this,just Remove this line

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView1"
```

from your `ImageView`

Comment: See results https://www.dropbox.com/s/tjw1raf224aaq6l/device-2017-10-05-185647%20copy.png?dl=0. Now vertical distance between textView1 and imageView is about 40dp.

Answer (score 1):

The first two answer will work. You can also add `app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"` to the top `ImageView` if you want to maintain your vertical chain.

Here is an image after adding this statement (but not changing anything else.)

[image]

Here is the XML:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:srcCompat="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,16:9"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:text="Subtle"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView1"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**Update:** So the above doesn't work on API 23 with `ConstraintLayout` version 1.0.2. Try the following instead:

Remove `android:layout_marginTop="16dp"` from `textView2` and add `android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"` to `textView1`. This makes a difference.

Comment: The first two answer don't work, I get around 40dp distance between textView1 and imageView https://www.dropbox.com/s/tjw1raf224aaq6l/device-2017-10-05-185647%20copy.png?dl=0. With "spread_inside" I got no vertical margin between textView1 and textView2. See this screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/59nixtlhnah44j7/device-2017-10-05-190906.png?dl=0.

Comment: Just copied/pasted your source code and get these results on Nexus 5 simulator running on API 23 and the same results on real Nexus 5 running on API 23 https://www.dropbox.com/s/x48wk7sgk4ma6d5/Screenshot_1507223903.png?dl=0. As you can see now there's no space between textView1 and textView2.

Comment: Tell me please, what constraint-layout version do you use @Cheticamp?

Comment: @EugeneBrusov I think we had this conversation earlier with another one of your questions. I use the latest beta release: 1.1.0-beta2. If you don't want to run a beta release (understandable), you may want to consider 1.0.1 as the latest production release if you aren't already running it.

Comment: Ah, I see now... Yep, 1.1.0-beta2 solves many problems except for it's in still in beta yet. Anyway thanks for testing this out for me!

Comment: @EugeneBrusov I am curious about which ConstraintLayout version you are using.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156036/discussion-between-eugene-brusov-and-cheticamp).

Comment: @EugeneBrusov Look at the bottom of the answer. I added a fix for your setup.

Answer (score 1):

The gist of it is to use a packed chain, with a vertical bias of 0, so that the content of the chain will be at the top. Also, I'm not sure why you are using a FrameLayout -- you probably don't need to.

[image]

With 1.1.0-beta2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView1"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,16:9"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        app:srcCompat="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:text="Subtle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Yep, packed chain fixes all the vertical margins in the requested layout even with constraint-layout v1.0.2. I used FrameLayout only for test purposes as a root layout since I wanted to see the way ConstraintLayout wraps content. I can use ConstraintLayout with `layout_height="wrap_content"` for example as a RecyclerView item.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -> I removed `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView1"` in the `ImageView` and it works fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:srcCompat="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,16:9"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:text="Subtle"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView1"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: See results dropbox.com/s/tjw1raf224aaq6l/…. Now vertical distance between textView1 and imageView is about 40dp.