# Android - RecyclerView Grid aligned Start and end but centered and same space between each row

Tags: android

Im trying to achieve a recyclerView with a gridLayout with 3 columns and 2 rows.

i need the first column aligned to the start parent and the third row aligned to the end of the parent. Of course the second column has to be centered in the parent.

How can i achieve this?

[image]

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewAccessHome"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textViewAccesos"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            tools:listitem="@layout/cell_accesos_menu_home"
            app:layoutManager="GridLayoutManager"
            app:spanCount="3"
            tools:itemCount="6"
            android:clipToPadding="false"/>
```

**And the cell**

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
android:id="@+id/card_menu_access_home"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="90dp"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:paddingHorizontal="15dp"
android:paddingVertical="17dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="15dp">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewCellRWHAccessHome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic__close"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewCellRWHAccessHome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text here"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
        android:lines="2"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

I achieved it with this code, idk if it is correct.

`recyclerViewAccessHome.addItemDecoration(HomeItemDecorator())`

```
class HomeItemDecorator : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {

private var space = 22

override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect, view: View, parent: RecyclerView, state: State) {

    outRect.left = space;
    outRect.right = space;
    outRect.bottom = space;
    outRect.top = space;

    if(parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 2 || parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 5) {
        outRect.right = 0;
    }

    if(parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 0 || parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 3) {
        outRect.left = 0;
    }

    if(parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 1 || parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) ==4) {
        outRect.left = space / 2;
        outRect.right = space / 2;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add dividers and spaces between items in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618829/how-to-add-dividers-and-spaces-between-items-in-recyclerview)

Comment: Look specifically at the ItemDecoration post, and modify the "out rect" based on your item's position.

Comment: Couldnt achieve it :(

Comment: Well, update with what you've come up with and I'll help with a solution.

Comment: Post edited. I achieve it with that code, but idk if it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Update your item view

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```