# DividerItemDecoration vs LinearLayoutManager in android recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

can anyone explain the difference between DividerItemDecoration and LinearLayoutManager?

when should i use DividerItemDecoration and when should i use LinearLayoutManager in recycler view?

Answer (score 0):

LinearLayoutManager and DividerItemDecoration has entirely different use cases.

When you use a RecyclerView, you need to specify a LayoutManager that is responsible for laying out each item in the view. The LinearLayoutManager is a type of LayoutManager which allows you to specify an orientation, just like a normal LinearLayout would.

DividerItemDecoration is a RecyclerView.ItemDecoration that can be used as a divider between items of a LinearLayoutManager. For providing spaces or divider between your RecyclerView item you can use DividerItemDecoration.

[LinearLayoutManager is explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28460399/4639479)

[DividerItemDecoration is explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27037230/4639479)