# View in the view pager overlap between previous and next view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment

I am using ViewPager for sliding effect in my app.

I have pager.setPageMargin() to make next and previous views visibility, unfortunately my next view is over lapping with current view.

Below is my code

```
pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myviewpager);

    adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(this, this.getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(adapter);



    // Set current item to the middle page so we can fling to both
    // directions left and right
    pager.setCurrentItem(FIRST_PAGE);

    // Necessary or the pager will only have one extra page to show
    // make this at least however many pages you can see
    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(10);

    // Set margin for pages as a negative number, so a part of next and 
    // previous pages will be showed

    //
    pager.setPageMargin(-450);
```

I am using fragment in the pager. 
I am getting output as attached with this thread, but need views being place properly with out over lapping

[image]

part marked in above picture should go behind the centre card.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android ViewPager - Show preview of page on left and right](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098040/android-viewpager-show-preview-of-page-on-left-and-right)

Comment: @BillyRiantono its not duplicate, in the attached picture if you see i am displaying next card, but next card (marked in oval) is overlaid on current card(centre card)

Comment: Hi @Suresh Did you have solution for your case ?

Comment: Hi @Suresh Did you have solution for your problem

Comment: @androiuseru sorry guy i dont recollect what is the solution I used to solve this since its long time.

Answer (score 1):

since you are setting pager.setPageMargin(-450); you also need to give 240 padding to the ViewPage's child fragment and  pager.setClipToPadding(false); for smooth animation.

if someone still looking for solution, I had customized the ViewPage to achieve it without using negative margin, find a sample project here https://github.com/44kksharma/Android-ViewPager-Carousel-UI
it should work in most cases but you can still define page margin with
 `mPager.setPageMargin(margin in pixel);`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    pager.setClipToPadding(false);
    pager.setPadding(50, 0, 50, 0);
```

instead of:

```
    pager.setPageMargin(-450);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually i brought the required view to the front

```
view.bringToFront();
```

Note: Want to identify the correct Layout which is in centre of view pager's current displaying page

Comment: Can you please say how did you identify the correct layout that is in centre of view pager?

Answer (score 0):

```
pager.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
pager.setPageMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

You just use match_parent for height and width of viewpaper
tks.
hope it useful for you

Answer (score 0):

I’ve find a solution for post-KitKat version. Basically what I did is increase the elevation of the current center view. (I'm still working for pre-Lollipop solution)

Here's my code, Set an OnPageChangeListener to your viewpager and, in OnPageSelected Method

```
     @Override public void onPageSelected(int position) {

      //Counter for loop
      int count = 0;
      int PAGER_LOOP_THRESHOLD = 2;
      if (position >= PAGER_LOOP_THRESHOLD) {
        count = position - PAGER_LOOP_THRESHOLD;
      }
      do {
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) adapter.instantiateItem(pager, count);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP
            && fragment.getView() != null) {

          //If it's current center position, increase view's elevation. Otherwise, we reduce elevation
          if (count == position) {
            fragment.getView().setElevation(8.0f);
          }
          else {
            fragment.getView().setElevation(0.0f);
          }
        }
        count++;
      } while (count < position + PAGER_LOOP_THRESHOLD);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the viewpager items are stacked like a stack. so when it gives a margin value, only a space is added in between. For this, you should use transformer and set the translationZ value for these features.

There are usually 3 views and you have to set the position for each.

```
position < 0 -> {
  alpha = 1f
  translationX = -width * MAX_SCALE * position
  ViewCompat.setTranslationZ(this, position)
  val scaleFactor = (MIN_SCALE
                       + (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - abs(position)))
  scaleX = scaleFactor
  scaleY = scaleFactor
}
```

Also you can define 0.75f max and min scale. For all code:

```
override fun transformPage(view: View, position: Float) {
        with(view) {
            when {
                position < -1 -> {
                    alpha = 1f
                }
                position < 0 -> {
                    alpha = 1f
                    translationX = -width * MAX_SCALE * position
                    ViewCompat.setTranslationZ(this, position)
                    val scaleFactor = (MIN_SCALE
                            + (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - abs(position)))
                    scaleX = scaleFactor
                    scaleY = scaleFactor
                }
                position == 0f -> {
                    alpha = 1f
                    scaleX = 1f
                    scaleY = 1f
                    translationX = 0f
                    ViewCompat.setTranslationZ(this, 0f)
                }
                position <= 1 -> {
                    alpha = 1f
                    translationX = width * MAX_SCALE * -position
                    ViewCompat.setTranslationZ(this, -position)
                    val scaleFactor = (MIN_SCALE
                            + (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - abs(position)))
                    scaleX = scaleFactor
                    scaleY = scaleFactor
                }
                else -> {
                    alpha = 1f
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You should apply it to the class you created

```
class OverlapPageTransformer : ViewPager2.PageTransformer {
     override fun transformPage(view: View, position: Float) {}
}
```

Last;

```
 yourPager.apply {
     setPageTransformer(OverlapPageTransformer())
 }
```