# Make ViewPager like on picture

Tags: android

I try to write `PageTransformer` for `ViewPager`

```
viewPager.setPageTransformer(false, new ViewPager.PageTransformer() {
     @Override
     public void transformPage(View page, float position) {
          float factor = (float)Math.pow(0.5, Math.abs(position));
          page.setScaleX(factor);
          page.setScaleY(factor);
     }
});
```

But it works only if I don't set padding and page margins. How to fix this code if padding and page margins not 0?
I need view like below and animation on scroll
[image]

Comment: Maybe this repo will help you - otherwise it is hard to tell exactly what you're asking. https://github.com/ToxicBakery/ViewPagerTransforms

Comment: also you should try this solution with own customization http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098040/android-viewpager-show-preview-of-page-on-left-and-right

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use this library because it use more higher API version. I fixed transformation. But ViewCard drop shadow doesn't draw on previous and next pages, only on backgorund... How I can fix it?

Comment: let me know if you are still looking for the solution we can work on it. check out my answer below if that can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get an Idea from my sample project, I also used PageTransformer

I had customized the ViewPage to achieve it without using negative margin, find a sample project here https://github.com/44kksharma/Android-ViewPager-Carousel-UI
it should work in most cases but you can still define page margin with
 `mPager.setPageMargin(margin in pixel);`

[image]