# How to design swiping images slideshow ? Which approach would be good to achieve a view like this?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I do not know how to implement this kind of view of slider.Can anyone guide me with it or any library?

[image]

Comment: Using `ViewPager`.

Comment: @Mann how can i preview previous and next images with it ?

Comment: A viewpager with circular pager indicator.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23356010/4321808 refer to this answer

Comment: Have a look at this library https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider
hope this will help you.

Comment: @Ritesh  how can i focus the selected pager item as in image

Comment: @RaviTeja can you just tell me how can i zoom up the centre image? I am using gallery view. please help thanks.

Comment: @AshleshaSharma can you just tell me how can i zoom up the centre image? I am using gallery view. please help thanks.

Comment: @Mann can you just tell me how can i zoom up the centre image? I am using gallery view. please help thanks.

Comment: You can follow this tutorial for center zoomed image.
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-displaying-images-with-an-enhanced-gallery--mobile-11130

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this link, its easily understood and does what u want.

http://www.androprogrammer.com/2015/06/view-pager-with-circular-indicator.html

Comment: can you just tell me how can i zoom up the centre image? I am using gallery view. please help thanks.

Comment: please see the image in my question in which twitter logo is coming up and others are in bacground

Answer (score 0):

This is actually referred as carousel. Kindly view the following link :

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/838

This library contains variations and 'simple example' of demo app is near to your requirement.

Comment: can you just tell me how can i zoom up the centre image? I am using gallery view. please help thanks.

Comment: @AndroidGeek kindly see this : http://prntscr.com/amsgl2. I assume the library handles this itself. In your case, you have to adjust the spaces between your images.

Answer (score 0):

adjust the margin with mPager.setPageMargin(margin in pixel); in the sample project to achieve above effect

I had customized the ViewPage to achieve it without using negative margin, find a sample project here https://github.com/44kksharma/Android-ViewPager-Carousel-UI
it should work in most cases but you can still define page margin with
 `mPager.setPageMargin(margin in pixel);`

[image]