# Android pinch-to-zoom layout inside a viewpager with padding left and right

Tags: android, android-viewpager, zooming, scale, pinchzoom

I have a viewpager with left and right padding for showing the previews of left and right pages of viewpager.

```
viewPager.setPadding(30,0,30,0);
```

The content of the viewpager is a zoomlayout borrowed from [here](https://github.com/shopgun/zoomlayout).
So the issue is, whenever I zoom the layout from the viewpager, the only visible zoom is at top and bottom. Zooming is not visible to the left and right due to padding.

Screenshot before zooming
[image: Normal View without zooming (pinch to zoom)]

Screenshot after zooming
[image: Pinch to zoom]
[image: Pinch to zoom]

The zoomed view is limited inside the viewpager padding. I need the view to zoom fullscreen without any padding or boundaries.

These are the code snippets I was trying

activity_reader.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/reader_pager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

each_page.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<com.test.poc.widgets.ZoomLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/zoom_layout">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/img_holder"
        android:transitionName="pager"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/page_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/a_four"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</com.test.poc.widgets.ZoomLayout>
```

After zooming the view, when I release the finger, the view should move smoothly to a fullscreen viewpager.

Tried setting clipToPadding as false, but still one side of padding still exist while zooming

Answer (score 0):

Did you try putting zoomview beside viewpager in framelayout (not in each page) so it is on top of viewpager.

Comment: I want to zoom each page of viewpager. That padding is for left and right preview. Zoomview should work from left and right also. I have to zoom the layouts of left and right also

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's worked for me using this :https://gist.github.com/atermenji/3781644

```
public class ImageZoomViewPager extends ViewPager {

public ImageZoomViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ImageZoomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected boolean canScroll(View v, boolean checkV, int dx, int x, int y) {
    if (v instanceof ImageViewTouch) {
        return ((ImageViewTouch) v).canScroll(dx);
    } else {
        return super.canScroll(v, checkV, dx, x, y);
    }
}}
```

Comment: Tried this before. Still the left and right portion of the zoomed view is cut (due to padding).