# Viewpager2 scrolling on preview left and right is not working

Tags: android, android-viewpager2

I have implemented Viewpager2 with left and right preview as shown in Image below. But **scrolling only work on Middle Item(2)**. Not on left(1) and right(3) item preview. **How to make scrolling work on left and right preview**.

[image]

```
  <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/_50sdp"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_50sdp"
            />
```

Java code

```
    viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    viewpager.setClipToPadding(false);
    viewpager.setClipChildren(false);


    CompositePageTransformer cpt = new CompositePageTransformer();

    cpt.addTransformer(new MarginPageTransformer(10));
    cpt.addTransformer(new ViewPager2.PageTransformer() {
        @Override
        public void transformPage(@NonNull View page, float position) {
            float r = 1 - Math.abs(position);
            page.setScaleY(0.80f + r * 0.20f);
        }
    });

   viewpager.setPageTransformer(cpt);
   viewpager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);

            
            if (position == 0) {
                viewpager.setCurrentItem((int) (A1.list.size() / 2));

            }
            
        }
    });
```

Comment: Here is Optimized Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73397935/5773037

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I honestly didn't find a true mean to make Viewpager2 works with swiping events on left and right preview since Viewpager2 class is final. But things worked out very well with using NestedScrollview.

**UPDATED NEW SOLUTION IN KOTLIN**
Thanks to CmTiger I have created a better solution

1: **Add this to Nested ScrollView**

```
   var last_x = 0f
 
   viewpager2Scroller.setOnTouchListener(object : OnTouchListener {
            var LEFT_RIGHT =  (padding * -1) // your offsets
            var RIGHT_LEFT = padding
            override fun onTouch(view: View, motionEvent: MotionEvent): Boolean {
                val x = motionEvent.xPrecision
                if (x > last_x) {
                    motionEvent.offsetLocation(LEFT_RIGHT.toFloat(), 0f)
                } else {
                    motionEvent.offsetLocation(RIGHT_LEFT.toFloat(), 0f)
                }
                last_x = x
                viewpager2.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent)
                return false
            }
        })
```

2: Add this To Viewpager2

```
  viewpager2.setOnTouchListener(object : View.OnTouchListener {
            var lastValue = 0f
            var value = 0f
            var delta = 0f
            override fun onTouch(view: View, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
                if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    lastValue = event.x
                    viewpager2.beginFakeDrag()
                } else if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                    value = event.x
                    delta = value - lastValue
                    viewpager2.fakeDragBy(delta * 2)
                    lastValue = value
                } else if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL || event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    viewpager2.endFakeDrag()
                }
                return false
            }
        })
```

To **Handle Crash** when setting the item ourself

```
if (!binding.viewpager2.isFakeDragging) {
        binding.viewpager2.setCurrentItem(list.size / 2, false)
    }
```

---

**OLD SOLUTION**

```
          <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nestedScroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/_50sdp"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_50sdp"
            />
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Just use this code to make it work. Increase int value of **speed** to increase speed and vice versa.

```
  nestedScroll = view.findViewById(R.id.nestedScroll);

    nestedScroll2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        float start = 0;
        float limit_to_start_moving = 5;
        int speed = 7;
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                // Touch Starts X  DOWN_X
                start = motionEvent.getX();
            }

            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                // get position
                float X2 = motionEvent.getX();

                if ((X2 - limit_to_start_moving) > start) {
                    // LEFT & RIGHT DIRECTION
                    if (start < X2)
                        viewpager.fakeDragBy((motionEvent.getXPrecision() * speed));
                    else
                        viewpager.fakeDragBy((motionEvent.getXPrecision() * -speed));
                    start = X2;  // old position

                } else if ((X2 + limit_to_start_moving) < start) {

                    if (start < X2)
                        viewpager.fakeDragBy((motionEvent.getXPrecision() * speed));
                    else
                        viewpager.fakeDragBy((motionEvent.getXPrecision() * -speed));
                    start = X2;

                }
            }

            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                if (viewpager.isFakeDragging()) {
                    viewpager.endFakeDrag();
                }

            }

            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {

                if (viewpager.isFakeDragging()) {
                    viewpager.endFakeDrag();
                    if (start > motionEvent.getX()) {
                        viewpager.setCurrentItem(viewpager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
                    } else {
                        viewpager.setCurrentItem(viewpager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
                    }
                }

            }

            return false;
        }
    });

   viewpager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            float lastValue;
            float value;
            float delta;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    lastValue = event.getX();
                    viewpager.beginFakeDrag();
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                    value = event.getX();
                    delta = value - lastValue;
                    viewpager.fakeDragBy(delta * 2);
                    lastValue = value;
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    viewpager.endFakeDrag();
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I took your solution and made it much simpler and the scrolling is handle natively by the ViewPager:

```
view.findViewById(R.id.nestScrollView).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        final int x_offset = -Tools.dpToPx(30);
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            motionEvent.offsetLocation(x_offset,0);
            VP_dynamic_area.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

x_offset should be equal to the padding we gave to the ViewPager.
I modified the motionEvent so the touch will be on the ViewPager and not on the padding area.

Comment: Thanks man! I have updated my answer. You answer was only working at one side of preview.  but it was easy. thanks.

Comment: But after thorough testing. there is some problem. This solution needs more optimization in my case.  I am ok with the old one.  Don't have much time.