# Viewpager2 left and right preview item scrolling not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager2

I am trying to create an image slider using ViewPager2 with left and right previews. Everything is working perfectly, but scrolling on left and right preview items is not working.

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63667356/4854891), but it's not working for me as well.

[image: sample image]

Above image copied from [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63667356/4854891)

Sample XML code

```
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2 
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:paddingEnd="60dp"
    android:paddingStart="60dp" />
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Viewpager2 scrolling on preview left and right is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63667356/viewpager2-scrolling-on-preview-left-and-right-is-not-working)

Comment: Nope, I have mentioned that in my question. BTW, thanks for you suggestion.

Comment: Add some left - right margin to the Views inside the viewpager2

Answer (score 1):

##### Single Line Implementation with Kotlin Extention for ViewPager2

1. Single Line Implementation in your Activity or Fragment.

   ```
   binding.viewpager2.setPreviewBothSide(R.dimen._20sdp,R.dimen._35sdp)
   ```
2. Add Below Code in `HorizontalMarginItemDecoration.kt` file in your Project

   ```
   import android.content.Context
   import android.graphics.Rect
   import android.view.View
   import androidx.annotation.DimenRes
   import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
   import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2

   class HorizontalMarginItemDecoration(context: Context, @DimenRes horizontalMarginInDp: Int) :
       RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {
       private val horizontalMarginInPx: Int =
           context.resources.getDimension(horizontalMarginInDp).toInt()

       override fun getItemOffsets(
           outRect: Rect, view: View, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State
       ) {
           outRect.right = horizontalMarginInPx
           outRect.left = horizontalMarginInPx
       }
   }

   fun ViewPager2.setPreviewBothSide(@DimenRes nextItemVisibleSize: Int,@DimenRes currentItemHorizontalMargin: Int) {
       this.offscreenPageLimit = 1
       val nextItemVisiblePx = resources.getDimension(nextItemVisibleSize)
       val currentItemHorizontalMarginPx = resources.getDimension(currentItemHorizontalMargin)
       val pageTranslationX = nextItemVisiblePx + currentItemHorizontalMarginPx
       val pageTransformer = ViewPager2.PageTransformer { page: View, position: Float ->
           page.translationX = -pageTranslationX * position
           page.scaleY = 1 - (0.25f * kotlin.math.abs(position))
       }
       this.setPageTransformer(pageTransformer)

       val itemDecoration = HorizontalMarginItemDecoration(
           context,
           currentItemHorizontalMargin
       )
       this.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration)
   }
   ```
3. And Yes Here you got this Amazing Output

   [image]

   You Can Also Check out my Answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73397935/5773037)